# What is this grid-like pattern on the sky in photos?

Tags: nikon, sensor

Some photos of the sky taken on our Nikon D5100 have a diamond-like grid pattern. I'd like to know what may be the cause. The photo was taken in RAW and the pattern appears regardless whether it was processed with Apple Photos, Nikon's own software, or RawTherapee:

[image: photo 1]

Here it is (cropped) with contrast increased:

[image]

Lens: AF-S DX VR Zoom-Nikkor 55-200mm ƒ4-5.6G IF-ED

ISO 250, 82 mm, 0.3 ev, ƒ6.3, 1/400 s

[Here's the original NEF file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/0qraa5qhbd37a59/DSC_0211.NEF?dl=0)

Another picture, taken on different day:

[image]

AF-S DX VR Zoom-Nikkor 55-200mm ƒ4-5.6G IF-ED

ISO 160, 247 mm, -1 ev, ƒ5.3, 1/1000 s

[original NEF file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/8sytc8xuv03hh5s/DSC_0010.NEF?dl=0)

Comment: Was this taken from inside a vehicle, through the windshield or a closed side window?

Comment: No, it was taken outside, no filters on lens, nothing between the lens and the air.

Comment: Using Nikon's software, if you disable lens correction, does the pattern go away?

Comment: @scottbb Unfortunately not, the pattern is still there. Here's the original NEF if someone wants to play with it: https://www.dropbox.com/s/0qraa5qhbd37a59/DSC_0211.NEF?dl=0

Comment: Is the detail a screen shot or a digital crop of the full image?

Comment: Is the pattern visible in a print?

Comment: @BobMacaroniMcStevens The high contrast frame appears to be a crop of the upper left quadrant of the image. The pattern is also visible in the full image, just not as well defined with the more normal level of contrast.

Comment: @BobMacaroniMcStevens it's a crop. I didn't try printing it.

Comment: I developed the NEF with RawTherapee and applied very high contrast in GIMP and the grid is not reproducable. https://www.dropbox.com/s/qlpv83c4a3kremx/Screenshot%20from%202021-12-09%2009-50-38.png?dl=0 I suspect, therefore, that your grid is related somehow to the software you used.

Comment: @chili555 Interesting, I tried RawTherapee before, including for this photo, and the grid was still there. Perhaps, high contrast got rid of the whole sky including the grid? I'll try again.

Comment: @chili555 yeah, the grid is still there: https://www.dropbox.com/s/x0igoaun27lg2hg/rawtherapy.png?dl=0  Increasing contrast all the way just hides the sky completely.

Comment: Tried in Photoshop, also see the diamond pattern. Could this be an offset anti-aliasing filter on the sensor?

Comment: On a side note, you have to push way beyond normal editing for the pattern to become really visible. Like shadows +100, highlights -100 and then adding contrast- it could be that there is some basic processing in the RAW that then become visible. RAW is not always like raw sensor values.

Comment: You might simply hit the ceiling regarding dynamic range with the editing and what you see is the image falling apart. The example image is the attempt to create a HDR our of a single image with very high dynamic range.

Answer (score 1):

You can do an experiment to isolate the problem and possibly rule out something happening in the lens electronics.

First, if you have another lens, try it! I assume you would have done this already were it an option, but I mention it just in case.

Second, take an exposure with the lens off and point the naked sensor at something gray like the sky, so it stands out the same. If the noise is still there, it's probably that decade old sensor failing on you.

Comment: Thanks for suggestions. The other lens (AF-S DX VR Zoom-Nikkor 18-55mm ƒ3.5-5.6G) also produces the grid, so it may be indeed a problem with the sensor. The camera was used frequently for first few years, and then was left unused for a few years.

Answer (score 1):

One thing ahead: A RAW files usually is not as "raw" sensor data as many think. There might be some processing even on that data.

What I believe, we see here, is the processing of the RAW within the camera becoming visible. To see the artifacts, you have to push the image beyond usual processing - and probably beyond the dynamic range of the sensor.

I also found out that the problem becomes less pronounced if you apply the profile corrections for the lens you used.

I am attaching the images from Adobe RAW here. Sorry for using the German version here. But I think you can interpolate the settings from the description.

**Neutral Image**
[image: Image Neutral]

**Image with Black pushed -100**
[image: Image Pushed Black -100]

**Image with pushed Blacks and Lens Profile**
[image: Image Pushed Black -100 with Profile]

So what you do, is to change some of the image by -3 f-stops. This might be enough to introduce some sort of artifacts. Although I never saw diamond shaped banding, this might just be what happens.

If you look on the histogram you see that at -100 Black, a tiny sliver of the histogram becomes almost 50% of the histogram. The tonality here is stretched pretty much to the breaking point.

**One Solution**

If you take images that need such a wide dynamic range, you might be better using bracketing - i.e. taking several images with different shutter speeds and use a hdr software or even just photoshop to combine them into an hdr image. This way you conserve the areas where your camera is best while also having more information to work with.
Your camera can do automated bracketing, so unless you have a lot of movement in your image, this would be the way to go.

Comment: @DmitryChestnykh I added bracketing as a potential solution to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have personally observed this type of pattern on clear day blue sky with the naked eye. I was wearing polarized sunglasses, I took them off and the hexagon pattern was still visible without the glasses.

I observed this in 2021 mid-spring in Montreal, Canada.

Here is a thread on Reddit I discovered.

Comment: You seem to have forgotten the link, please [edit] it in.

Comment: Interesting theory, however I haven't seen this pattern with my eyes (or via the lens when shooting), and it didn't appear in iPhone photos of the same subject.